# What is meant by data back to its original state?

Tags: machine-learning

I have started to learn machine learning and is following Aurelien Geron's *Hands on machine learning with Scikit-learn Keras and Tensorflow*.

In the second chapter, I came through a line following a code

```
Now you should remove the income_cat attribute so the data is back to its original
state:

for set_ in (strat_train_set, strat_test_set):
    set_.drop("income_cat", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

i can't understand what the writer meant by *removing an attribute* and *the data is back to original*?

For clarification, it's a house price prediction problem and **median_income**  is a feature. The **median_income** has been categorized through **income_cat** and is used for stratified sampling.

You can check from In[23] to In[31] in the following link of a Jupyter Notebook ( provided by the author ) for more clarification :

https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/02_end_to_end_machine_learning_project.ipynb

Pardon me if the question seems dumb. I am a novice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the book it says you add a new income category 'attribute' to the data by doing some calculations on the original data.

You then remove this new attribute later on to get the original data back. The only reason to remove it is he wants to get his original data back.

In other words you start with x amount of attributes for each data point, (one of which is 'median_income'), you add a new attribute to each data point ('income_cat') so you now have x+1 attributes for each data point. You then remove the data point later as he wants to get his original data back.

Comment: Thanks! It was really helpful. :)